# Is pygame module, 'pygame.event.get()' not work on method?

Tags: python, events, methods, keyboard, pygame

I made a game and used pygame module as the keyboard input. 
however, it does not seem to respond. 
there is no error, but my keypress does nothing when I run the code.

I tried using pygame.key but it does not work.

I have no idea what is wrong with this code.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()


class keypress():
    def check(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    print("Hey, you pressed the key, '0'!")
                if event.key == pygame.K_1:
                    print("Doing whatever")
                else:
                    pass


a = keypress()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        a.check()
```

When I press keys, it does basically nothing.

Comment: Not a *PyGame* expert but using `pygame.KEYDOWN` for an event type and key seems a bit odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pygame [will not work without a screen/window defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34347973/run-pygame-without-a-window-gui/34360142#34360142).

With a window opened, and a couple of minor bugs in the input-handling fixed ~

- event.key needs to check for `pygame.K_0`, not `KEYDOWN` again
- Indentation is weird in `main` loop.
- There's (still) no way to exit

It works mostly how the code seems to describe:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
WINDOW_WIDTH = 400
WINDOW_HEIGHT= 400
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT))

class keypress():
    def check(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                # TODO - handle exiting
                pass
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_0:
                    print("Hey, you pressed the key, '0'!")
                elif event.key == pygame.K_1:
                    print("Doing whatever")


a = keypress()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        a.check()
```

Comment: Thank you. what module can I use instead?

Comment: @ONLYIFYOUCANREAD A module to handle keyboard input without a window open?